# Getting the port name of a connected USB device

Tags: c#, windows, usb

When a USB device is connected to the computer, how can I get the PORT name which it is connected using C# code.
I found many ways to find when a USB is connected, disconnected, drive letter, path, device id etc. but didn't find any clear example on how to know to which port it got connected. I saw one possible explanation but that involves lot of pinvokes which I totally don't understand.
I like to believe there are more direct and easy ways to get such info in c# alone, without using any unmanaged code.

Comment: I'm creating an App and when I plug in my USB modem I want that to select the port automatically right now I'm selecting it manually. I only want to get the connected COM port through which a specific USB is connected (getting the COM port, may be searching by USB device id).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use a **C#** to **USB** device library
as described here:
[Are there any good C# to usb device libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707111/are-there-any-good-c-to-usb-device-libraries)

From the above answer: For getting a list of devices connected:
http://code.google.com/p/usb-devices-list/

Answer (score 11):

USB ports don't have names.  It is a bus, it doesn't matter what connector you use.  Just like it doesn't matter where you plug in a card in the bus inside of the machine.

If you are actually talking about a USB device whose driver emulates a serial port (like "COM5"), pretty common, then you can get some info about the driver out of a WMI query, Win32_SerialPort class.  Use the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) tool to play with such a query and to auto-generate the C# code you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the BUS. Correct; I want to get the driver emulated COM port. I'm creating an App and when I plug in my USB modem I want that to select the port automatically coz sometimes it change; right now I set it manually. Thanks for the WMI code creator it seems very useful. Can u give me any hint or help how to get the connected com ports using that, because it gives me 0 results when I try Win32_SerialPort class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a very nice library here [page 1](http://read.pudn.com/downloads105/sourcecode/windows/vxd/432626/USBLib/USB.cs__.htm) and here [page 2](http://read.pudn.com/downloads105/sourcecode/windows/vxd/432626/USBLib/Functions.cs__.htm)

The website is Chinese, but the code is not. It does not work for x64 (it'll compile, but the answers are bogus), but does work for x86.

Answer (score 1):

COM port number can be found with help of wmi services,
here is [a vbscript example for detecting usb com port number](http://collectns.blogspot.com/2011/11/vbscript-for-detecting-usb-serial-com.html)