# How to detect if a connected USB printer is on or off?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, usb

I want to detect if a printer is Online/offline  **BEFORE** attempting to print. 
If it is offline - the print dialog will not be Visible.

The Win32 API's "OpenPrinter" etc. seem to work on the spooler queue, rather
than the printer itself, and will only report the printer offline **AFTER** a
document is sent, whichis too late.

**QUESTION**:
How can I tell if a printer is offline/online without sending a print out to it?

EDIT:

```
Offline - printer is turned off
OnLine  - printer is turned On
```

Comment: What does online/offline mean for the purpose of this question? Does offline mean disconnected, or is there any other condition that you may want to catch this way?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you know the name of the printer or other details about it.

Well, then simply use `EnumPrinters` with `PRINTER_INFO_2` and check for `PRINTER_STATUS_OFFLINE` (or any other status that you want *avoid*).

Alternately you could try to use the `SetupDi*` functions (aka Setup API) to figure out whether the USB device matching the printer is connected at this very moment.

Comment: +1 Probing the USB matching device is good direction to go. Maybe that calls for a new post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

As you already found out this is abstracted using the spooler and the spooler status doesn't always reflect the printer status.

So this is by design in Windows.

If you only have one specific printer type you could query if it is attached to USB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838033/getting-the-port-name-of-a-connected-usb-device

Comment: Actually you can query this even with multiple printers connected.

Comment: Sure, I meant if the program has to query multiple printer types on different systems it could become more complicated.